# Compare two columns and return value from third

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, splunk, cross-correlation

I have three columns. The first two are lists of ip's and the third is a plain number that is associated to the ip in the second column.

I would like to check the following. IF a value from column A appears in column B then return the value from column C. An example can be found in the attached sheet.

I tried using the index formula in excel, but i have a problem. An ip from column B can have multiple different associated values in column C.

The second problem i have is the huge number of rows. I estimate that i should be checking more than 1 million of rows. Using excel will take me a huge ammount of time. Does anyone have any other suggestions? I've heard of Splunk but have no idea on how to use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is the attached sheet?

Comment: you could try using `countif`. `=IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$100000,A1)>0,C1,"")`

Comment: If an IP can appear in column B multiple times with different associated values in column C, what do you want to get back and in what format?